# Pyspark xpath evaluation org.xml.sax.SAXParseException;

Tags: xml, apache-spark, xpath, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have a pyspark dataframe like this.

```
name      |    content
abc.com,  |<html><head>\n<meta charset="UTF-8">\n<title>Yella Ball Tennis</title>\n</head>\n\n<body>\n<p>&nbsp;</p>\n<p>&nbsp;</p>\n<table width="369" border="0" align="center">\n  <tbody>\n    <tr>\n      <td align="center"><img src="logo_ybt.png" width="115" height="137" alt=""></td>\n    </tr>\n    <tr>\n      <td align="center" valign="top"><p><br>\n          <span style="font-family: \'Lucida Grande\', \'Lucida Sans Unicode\', \'Lucida Sans\', \'DejaVu Sans\', Verdana, sans-serif"><strong>Yella Ball Tennis will be your worldwide resource for finding regulation 78\' Yellow Ball Tennis (YBT) tournaments for all ages. Helping players, coaches and parents find and make choices! </strong></span></p>\n      <p><span style="font-family: \'Lucida Grande\', \'Lucida Sans Unicode\', \'Lucida Sans\', \'DejaVu Sans\', Verdana, sans-serif">If it has to do with 78\' regulation yellow ball tennis and tournaments for juniors \n      of all ages then you will find it here soon, including the most comprehensive list of regulation and dual path tournaments in the world.</span><br>\n      <br>\n      <span style="font-family: \'Lucida Grande\', \'Lucida Sans Unicode\', \'Lucida Sans\', \'DejaVu Sans\', Verdana, sans-serif">Stay tuned!</span><br>\n      <br>\n      <span style="font-family: \'Lucida Grande\', \'Lucida Sans Unicode\', \'Lucida Sans\', \'DejaVu Sans\', Verdana, sans-serif">In the mean time you can contact us at <a href="mailto:info@tennisdynamics.net">info@tennisdynamics.net</a> </span><br>\n      ...</p></td>\n    </tr>\n  </tbody>\n</table>\n<p>&nbsp;</p>\n\n</body></html>
```

And I am trying to apply xpath on column content and trying to extract texts inside `tbody` tag.

My code is

```
df.selectExpr('''xpath(content, "//tbody//text()")''').show()
```

and I get this error:

> Caused by: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 2; columnNumber: 3; The element type "head" must be terminated by the matching end-tag "".

But if you see the text, head is already closed properly with the end tag `</head>`.

Please help, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Your `tbody` contains `\n`, which is invalid XML content. Also, make sure your XML is completely valid. For example, your `meta` tag doesn't end

Comment: hi @pltc, I replace all \n to empty space, still same error. error is with head not completed same error